# Send email with attachment without saving to hard drive before

Tags: php, actionscript-3, email, encode

is it possible to send an email with an image attachement in a "text" format? (like in a ByteArray)

I'ld like to encode an image into an ByteArray (Flash AS3 - PNGencoder) and send it then via PHP to Gmail and others without saving the image to a hard drive before.

I'm totally researching on this so any information is welcome!

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Please clarify. What do you mean by "saving to a hard drive"? The client's, or the server's? Where do you want to send the E-Mail from?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [with SwiftMailer this is how you do it](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/dynamic-attachments) (or for [inline images](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/embedding-dynamic-content)).

You still have to encode your PNG data, [like this](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=720307).

Comment: Please let me know if this is enough or if you still need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. To be specific the PHP file is on my server and i don't want to save the image temporary. I tried this PHP but the image part isn't working. Link: http://pastebin.com/0Zh7qp8a

Comment: here is a link to my PHP: www.pastebin.com/0Zh7qp8a When I receive the email the there is an attached .PNG but with a size of 0kb